# TYPO3 - f:image 'crop' not working anymore after upgrade from 7LTS to 8LTS

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

In 7LTS I cropped https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Image.html#crop an image (original 1280+852) like this:

```
<f:image src="EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Images/sidewalk-min.jpg" crop="160,0,960,852" />
```

After upgrade to 8LTS the cropping is not working anymore and instead I get the original size. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can crop `image` in `fluid` like below.

```
<f:image src="EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Images/sidewalk-min.jpg" width="160c" height="852c" />
```

Comment: Yes I did in meantime. Cost me extra 2 hours to change it though :-)